# Query and table optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ECS.UserId,,PFR.EntityId,PFR.CreatedBy
FROM EventConsentStatus ECS 
INNER JOIN @Institutions I ON ECS.InstitutionId=I.InstitutionId             
LEFT JOIN ParentFormResponses PFR ON  PFR.EntityTypeId = 1 
          AND PFR.EntityId=@ActivityId AND ECS.EventId=PFR.EntityId                 
WHERE ECS.EventId = @ActivityId
```

A table called `ParentFormResponses` mentioned in the above query is having more than 3lacs records. Table is not having any identity column instead I have created clustered primary index on group of some columns based on uniqueness. But still it is taking more than 16 minutes to execute a simple select statement i.e. `select * from ParentFormResponses`.

If I am removing column names of ParentFormResponses table from above mentioned select statement then it is showing result in 2 3 seconds but for above query it is taking too much time.

If I create non clustered index on `entityid` and entitytypeid then also it is not giving optimized result.

Please suggest me how can I improve table structure and query performance.

**Detail information:**
Table Stucture:

```
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParentFormResponses](
[EntityId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FormId] [int] NOT NULL,
[StudentId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EntityTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FormVersion] [decimal](18, 1) NOT NULL,
[DigitallySigned] [bit] NULL,
[HasResponseChanged] [bit] NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_ParentFormResponses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EntityId] ASC,
    [FormId] ASC,
    [StudentId] ASC,
    [EntityTypeId] ASC,
    [FormVersion] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]`

**=>** I dropped primary key index and created below non clustered index
`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ParentFormResponses_sakshi_EntityId] ON [dbo].[ParentFormResponses_sakshi]
(
    [EntityId] ASC,
    [EntityTypeId] ASC,
    [FormId] ASC,
    [FormVersion] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [StudentId],
    [CreatedBy]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO`

**=>** Result of all three tables based on sp_spaceused are-

name-                      rows,   reserved,   data,       index_size, unused

ParentFormResponses    -        309961,    64704 KB,   63592 KB,   936 KB,     176 KB

ParentFormResponses_sakshi-    309893, 117696 KB,  60472 KB,   56944 KB,   280 KB

EventConsentStatus -        673796,    380920 KB,  109240 KB,  271512 KB,  168 KB

Note: Number of records are not 30k but more than 3 lacs. By mistake I wrote wrongly.

Comment: Do you know what a query plan is? If not - read is up. And post it. That said, start by making the Distinct surplus. That could possibly require a lot of work on the tempdb,  but then the query plan will tell you.

Comment: To select data from such a small table should not take long. It must be the fetching proces taking so long. Are you storing big data (images, videos, etc.)? I assume `select count(*) from ParentFormResponses` to take some seconds only. Correct? As to the join: an index on EntityId and EntityTypeId as mentioned by you should usually make this fast, at least when there are many different EntityIds.

Comment: Another question: estimated, how many users access table ParentFormResponses when running your query(es)?

Comment: Post the query plan .. also make sure that non clustered index you have created are actually being used and that statistics are up to date..

Comment: try use group by instead of distinct

Comment: Why is the Institutions table joined? (No column included in the result.)  You can try and move around the ActivityId condition, since it's for two different tables it can be placed in different places, also duplicated for both tables.

Comment: Please post the DDL of the table and indexes because "16 minutes to execute a simple select statement i.e. `select * from ParentFormResponses`" should be your only focus at the moment. It is worthless optimizing the query in your question when there is a major problem with at least one of the main tables. 30k is a very small table. Also, please do an `sp_spaceused ParentFormResponses` and `sp_spaceused EventConsentStatus` and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `distinct` and `left join` is suspicious from a performance perspective.  First, check the following query:

```
SELECT ECS.UserId, ECS.EntityId
FROM EventConsentStatus ECS INNER JOIN
     @Institutions I
     ON ECS.InstitutionId = I.InstitutionId             
WHERE ECS.EventId = @ActivityId;
```

You can optimize this with an index on `EventConsentStatus(EventId, UserId)`.  Assuming this has good performance, it will produce the right set of rows.  If not, then you may be getting duplicates from `@Institions`.  If this is the case, then consider removing it (no columns are used from that table, it is only for filtering).  Or:

```
SELECT ECS.UserId, ECS.EntityId
FROM EventConsentStatus ECS 
WHERE ECS.EventId = @ActivityId AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  @Institutions I WHERE ECS.InstitutionId = I.InstitutionId)
```

To get the right values, let's get the additional data using `outer apply`:

```
SELECT ECS.UserId, PFR.EntityId, PFR.CreatedBy
FROM EventConsentStatus ECS INNER JOIN
     @Institutions I
     ON ECS.InstitutionId = I.InstitutionId OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 PFR.EntityId, PFR.CreatedBy
      FROM ParentFormResponses pfr
      WHERE ECS.EventId = PFR.EntityId  AND
            PFR.EntityTypeId = 1 AND
            PFR.EntityId = @ActivityId
     ) pfr
WHERE ECS.EventId = @ActivityId;
```

For this, you want an index on `ParentFormResponses(EntityId, EntityTypeID, CreatedBy)`.

Comment: I have tried outer apply with proper indexes but still taking too much time. If I run both queries the one inside the Outer apply and the other one separately then it takes only few seconds. But with Left join or outer apply not giving optimized result.

Comment: @Sakshi . . . I just updated the index definition.  I had misread one the correlated `join` condition -- that affects the index and the performance.